# Getting checked state of a radiobutton

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the checked state of a radiobutton using jQuery without much luck.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="fr">
        <label>
            Recieve Email Updates?</label>

         Yes
            <input type="radio" value="True" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveSMS" id="ConsumerModel_RecieveSMS" data-val-required="The RecieveSMS field is required." data-val="true">
            No
            <input type="radio" value="False" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveSMS" id="ConsumerModel_RecieveSMS" checked="checked">
    </div>
<div class="fr">
        <label>
            Recieve Email Updates?</label>

         Yes
            <input type="radio" value="True" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveEmail" id="ConsumerModel_RecieveEmail" data-val-required="The RecieveEmail field is required." data-val="true" checked="checked">
            No
            <input type="radio" value="False" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveEmail" id="ConsumerModel_RecieveEmail">
    </div>
```

My jQuery looks like:

```
  var sms= $('input[name=ConsumerModel.RecieveSMS]:checked').val();
  var email = $('input[name=ConsumerModel.RecieveEmail]:checked').val();
```

My variable `sms` seems to be ok however email is always the same as `sms` even if the 2 are different.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ids _NEED TO BE_ unique. That's not valid html.

Comment: It's `receive`, not `recieve`

Comment: @Raynos: No, names **do not need** to be unique. Actually, they **have** to be equal for radio buttons to work. You are right about IDs though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is correct, but ids do need to be unique.

Comment: @ThiefMaster in XHTML doesn't an element need the same id & name?

Comment: ID's must be unique and are completely separate from names. The names must match in radiobuttons. ID's should be unique and that's only sensible, don't you think? It's an IDentifier...

Comment: IDs must always be unique. Classes and names don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you dont have unique names/ids your code breaks.

Check the [live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/xLWBh/2/).

Basically `$("input[name=...]:checked")` returns two elements rather then one.

```
<div class="fr">
    <label>
        Recieve Email Updates?</label>

    Yes
    <input type="radio" value="True" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveSMS" class="ConsumerModel_RecieveSMS" data-val-required="The RecieveSMS field is required." data-val="true">
    No
    <input type="radio" value="False" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveSMS" class="ConsumerModel_RecieveSMS" checked="checked">
</div>
<div class="fr">
    <label>
        Recieve Email Updates?</label>

    Yes
    <input type="radio" value="True" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveEmail" class="ConsumerModel_RecieveEmail" data-val-required="The RecieveEmail field is required." data-val="true" checked="checked">
    No
    <input type="radio" value="False" name="ConsumerModel.RecieveEmail" class="ConsumerModel_RecieveEmail">
</div>
```

If you change the `id` to a `class` which does not need to be unique then it works.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/xLWBh/5/)

Comment: Thanks Raynos, The online tool is pretty cool. First time ive seen it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio').is('checked');
```